# In an Intent Architect template, how can I check if an Attribute's type is an enum order to generate appropriate code?

Tags: c#, .net-core, intent-architect

I have a template which generates code for the attributes on a class. I need to check the type of each attribute and handle it differently for different types (in my case specifically I need to check for Enum properties).

e.g. Given something like this, how would I implement IsEnum?:

```
if (attribute.IsEnum()) {
    statements.Add($".HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<{attribute.Type.Element.Name}>());");
}
```

Comment: Please, is it possible to share the Enum with all properties and respective attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that you can achieve this is to use an Extension method that the Specialization Type of that Attribute in question.
Example:

```cs
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEnum(this AttributeModel attribute)
    {
        return attribute.Type.Element.SpecializationTypeId == EnumModel.SpecializationTypeId;
    }
}
```